# how to Access AngularJS object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Angular code. I am getting an array of `userInfo` through AngularJS services.

```
app.controller('personalController', function ($scope, $http, $window, userInfo) {

    $scope.info = userInfo.getValue();
    console.log( $scope.info);
    //$scope.data = $scope.info;
    console.log($scope.info.inf.CNIC);
}
```

This is my Angular service:

```
app.service('userInfo', function () {
    var infor = {};
    this.setValue = function (info) {
        infor["inf"] = info;
    }
    this.getValue = function (info) {
        return infor;
    }
})
```

I am getting the following values:

[image]

And I am getting `cannot read the property` error in `console.log($scope.info.inf.CNIC);`.

Comment: its because async behaviour console.log is excuting before anything is assinged to $scope.info

Comment: i am getting the value please check the "description here" Image

Comment: That's because `console.log`prints the updated version of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to reach to my angularjs objects.

In your controller you set

```
window.test = $scope;
```

Then in your developer console you can reach to your angular objects like below

```
test.info
```

Comment: i am new to angular please brief me more

Comment: You can set your controller scope to a window property("test" in this case) like `window.test = $scope;`. Then in your chrome developer console you can reach to your scope objects as you type `test.info`. (info or any other object in your scope)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome you can do the following:

Select the element you want to get the scope from via right-clicking and Inspect Element on from the browser, or selecting the element from the Elements tab of the Dev Tools, this will cause $0 to point to the element when referenced in the Dev Tools console.

In dev tools console you can use the below statement and get the scope:

```
angular.element($0).scope();
```

So to recap:

1. Right click on the element you want to get the scope and click inspect Element
2. type var sc = angular.element($0).scope();
3. Check the data inside **sc** variable